# redirect standard output for N level of child processes

Tags: c#, winapi, console-application, redirectstandardoutput

I'm successfully redirecting output when creating a single process.  However, when THAT process spawns additional processes, no output is being redirected.  Beyond creating the initial process, I have no control over how/when grandchildren processes are instantiated. It seems that the only other option might be a Win32 API call, but I found no evidence of such a method.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid there is no easy way to accomplish this when we have no control on spawning child process. 2 ways come to mind here:

**1-Man in the middle:** we replace the child executable with our own IO redirector executable, then it would start the real child process and redirect its IO to our own.

**2-Hooking Either CreateProcess or Std:** We can either intercept process creation and force redirection for all middle processes or intercept Std calls and report them to root.

*NOTE: please be aware that None of these methods would work 100%, they are very dependent to parent and child executable behaviors.*

I go with **Man in the Middle** as it is easier to implement and less fragile.

Let's assume we Have 3 executable:

**PA:** our root executable, we have full control of the code and behavior .

**PB:** our direct child executable, we can easily redirect the IO to our own process, but we don't have any control on the code and behavior.

**PC:** out indirect child spawning from **PB**, we have no control on it and we can't redirect IO normally as it is created by **PB** process.

[image: process]

what we can do here is to introduce another process **PI** which will be direct parent of **PC** and will redirect its IO to itself and then send it to our root process (**PA** in the example)

[image: process 2]

here are the codes for our 4 executables

to achieve this we have 4 executable (PA, PB, PC and PI) and a library which contains shared code for process rediraction and communication channel between **PA** and **PI** I used `NetMQ` in the sample as its is easy to use and reliable but it can be replaced with similar channels, we obtain the package through Nuget `PM> Install-Package NetMQ` .

Here is the code for our class library which is reference by both **PA** and **PI**:

```
public class RedirectProcess
{
    public static Process StartRedirected(string filename, string args = "")
    {
        var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            FileName = filename
        });

        process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        return process;
    }

    public static Process StartGrab(string filename, Action<string> dataHandle, string args = "")
    {
        var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            FileName = filename
        });

        process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => dataHandle(e.Data);
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        return process;
    }
}


public class RedirectClient:IDisposable
{
    private readonly NetMQContext _context;
    private readonly RequestSocket _socket;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public RedirectClient()
    {
        _context = NetMQContext.Create();
        _socket = _context.CreateRequestSocket();
        _socket.Connect("ipc://redirectCollector");
    }

    public void Send(string data)
    {
        _socket.Send(string.Format("{0},{1}", Id, data));
        _socket.Receive();//ack
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}


public class RediretServer:IDisposable
{
    private bool _start;
    public event EventHandler<ProcessDataArgs> ProcessDataReceived;

    public RediretServer()
    {
        _start = true;

       new Thread(() =>
       {
           using (var context = NetMQContext.Create())
           {
               var socket = context.CreateResponseSocket();
               socket.Bind("ipc://redirectCollector");

               while (_start)
               {
                   var res = socket.ReceiveString(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
                       continue;

                   if (ProcessDataReceived != null)
                       ProcessDataReceived(this, new ProcessDataArgs(res));

                   socket.Send(new byte[]{ });//ack
               }
           }
       }).Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _start = false;
    }
}


public class ProcessDataArgs:EventArgs
{
    public string Data { get;private set; }
    public int Id { get;private set; }

    public ProcessDataArgs(string result)
    {
        var i = result.IndexOf(','); //first comma

        Id = int.Parse(result.Substring(0, i));
        Data=result.Substring(i+1);
    }
}
```

and here are our executables:

**PA:** *(our main executable which all IO should get redirected to it)*

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new RediretServer();
        server.ProcessDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("pid:{0}, data:{1}", e.Id, e.Data);

        RedirectProcess.StartGrab("PB.exe", Console.WriteLine);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process A, ID: {0},- Hello", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**PB:** *(just for simulating the situation, our direct child we can easily redirect its IO to our own)*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Arguments = "-argument",
            FileName = "PC.exe"
        });

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process B, ID: {0},- Hello", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**PC:** *(the target nested child from **PB** which we want to redirect its IO)*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = args.Length == 0 ? "default" : args[0];

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process C, ID: {0}, Args: {1}- Hello", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, a);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**PI:** *(our redirector executable which we should replace **PC** with)*

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("**Process Redirector for PC**");

        var client = new RedirectClient();

        var interceptArgs = args
            .Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, a) => current + (string.Format("\"{0}\"", a)));

        var process=RedirectProcess.StartGrab("PC-real.exe", s =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            client.Send(s);
        },
            interceptArgs);

        client.Id = process.Id;
        process.WaitForExit();

        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

now lets build it and put all executables in one folder, if we run **PA** we should see two consoles pop up,**PA** but not **PC** the consoles output should be like:

**PA Output:** *(continuous stream)*

> Process A, ID: 85568,- Hello
>
> Process B, ID: 85640,- Hello

**PC Output:** *(continuous stream)*

> Process C, ID: 87012, Args: -argument- Hello

Not let's rename **PC.exe** to **PC-Real.exe** and out interceptor **PI.exe** to **PC.exe**.

if we run **PA** again, interceptor pops up instead of original **PC** and we will get its IO in out **PA** process.

> Process A, ID: 85144,- Hello
>
> Process B, ID: 86436,- Hello
>
> pid:83660, data:Process C, ID: 83660, Args: -argument- Hello

Comment: I don't have access to the code that generates any grandchild processes.  All I have control over is how the initial executable is launched.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way to do it, I think of 2 methods, each one is suitable to a specific situation, 1-man in the middle, which you can create an interceptor similar to one in the answer and put it as the original executable (child one), then this would do the redirection similar to single process and pass it up to the root or simply send it directly to root using a pipe, ipc channel or ... 2- Hooking either `StdHandle` or `CreateProcess` Win32 API using Hooking libraries like EasyHook, if you confirm one of these is useful, I can update my answer accordingly

Comment: Either one of those methods sounds promising. Look forward to your updated answer

Comment: @MitchA, updated the answer for man in the middle solution, hope this helps.

Comment: I may be off base here, but it looks like this solution only works if I know the names/locations of all child executables compile time  which I don't.  I don't know how many child processes will be spawned, let alone what their names are.

Comment: Not particularly,you can pass the process name as an argument to redirector process,number of child spawning doesn't matter but knowledge about executable image does,you need to put redirector in the middle for those ones,I don't know what you intend to do but, normally applications spawn specific executables (number of spawned child processes doesn't matter), so configuring redirector for them wouldn't be that hard, I'm may be wrong for your case, if you need high level of diversity for redirection, have look at `EasyHook` you can hook `CreateProcess` then use same method described above